Flyout Items transparent label, until I changed the size or move the Window
I have a very interesting problem.
in my app, when you log in, I am saving your email in secure storage, and navigate you to a certain page, where you can see items in your flyout depending on your choice.
When I run the app again, it will take me to this page (Because my email is saved) and I can see my flyout items, but they are transparent (I cannot see them, but they are there), If I resize the window, they turn back to normal, and I can see again.


Code Part
So, the first time the app runs, it goes to a StartupPage, to check if the user is already logged in or not.
public class StartupPageViewModel : BaseViewModel {

    private readonly IAppService _appService;
    private readonly ISecureStorage _secureStorage;
    IDataService<DemyUser> dataService;

    public StartupPageViewModel(IAppService appService, ISecureStorage secure, IDataService<DemyUser> dataService) {

        _appService = appService;
        _secureStorage = secure;
        this.dataService = dataService;
        CheckAuth();
    }

    private async void CheckAuth() {

        var currentUserEmail = await _secureStorage.GetAsync(Constants.LOGGED_USER);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUserEmail)) {
            if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI) {
                Shell.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}", true);
                });
            } else {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}", true);
            }
        } else {

            var loggedUser = await dataService.GetByEmailAsync(Constants.USERS,
                currentUserEmail);

            FlyoutHelper.CreateFlyoutHeader(loggedUser);

            FlyoutHelper.CreateFlyoutMenu(loggedUser?.CurrentRole!);

            await NvigationHelper.NavigatoToDashboardRoleAsync(loggedUser?.CurrentRole!);

        }
    }

here is when I create my header and my menu.
    public static void CreateFlyoutHeader(DemyUser? updatedUser) {
        IAppService appService = new AppService();

        Shell.Current.FlyoutHeader = new FlyoutHeader(
            new FlyoutHeaderViewModel(
                              $"{updatedUser!.Firstname} {updatedUser.Lastname}"!,
                              updatedUser.DemyId!,
                              updatedUser.Email!,
                              updatedUser.CurrentRole!,
                              appService
            ));
    }

    public static void CreateFlyoutMenu(string role) {

        switch (role) {

            case nameof(Roles.Student):
                CreateStudentItems();
                break;
            case nameof(Roles.Teacher):
                CreateTeacherItems();
                break;
            case nameof(Roles.Coordinator):
                CreateCoordintorItems();
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void CreateStudentItems() {
        var studentItems = new FlyoutItem() {
            Title = "Welcome",
            Route = nameof(StudentDashboardPage),
            FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
            Items = {

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "Welcome",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WelcomePage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "Join meeting",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(JoinMeetingPage)),
             }
        }
        };

        if (!Shell.Current.Items.Contains(studentItems)) {

            Shell.Current.Items.Add(studentItems);
        }

    }

    private static void CreateTeacherItems() {
        var TeacherItems = new FlyoutItem() {
            Title = "Welcome",
            Route = nameof(TeacherDashboardPage),
            FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
            Items = {

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "Welcome",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WelcomePage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "Join meeting",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(JoinMeetingPage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "My courses",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCoursesPage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "New lecture",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(NewLecturePage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "New Test",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(NewTestPage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "Schedule lecture",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(NewLecturePage)),
             },

             new ShellContent {
                 Title = "Schedule test",
                 ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ScheduleTestPage)),
             },
        }
        };

        if (!Shell.Current.Items.Contains(TeacherItems)) {

            Shell.Current.Items.Add(TeacherItems);

        }
    }

    private static void CreateCoordintorItems() {
        var CoordinatorItems = new FlyoutItem() {
            Title = "Welcome",
            Route = nameof(CoordinatorDashboardPage),
            FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
            Items = {

            new ShellContent {
                Title = "Welcome",
                ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WelcomePage)),
            },

            new ShellContent {
                Title = "Manage courses",
                ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ManageCoursePage)),
            },

            new ShellContent {
                Title = "Register student",
                ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(RegisterStudentPage)),
            }
        }
        };

        if (!Shell.Current.Items.Contains(CoordinatorItems)) {

            Shell.Current.Items.Add(CoordinatorItems);
        }
    }


    public static void GetDefaultMenuItems() {
        var defaultItems = new List<ShellContent> {

             new() { ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StartupPage)),
                Route = nameof(StartupPage), FlyoutItemIsVisible = false },
            new() { ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(LoginPage)),
                Route = nameof(LoginPage), FlyoutItemIsVisible = false },
            new() { ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(NoInternetPage)),
                Route = nameof(NoInternetPage), FlyoutItemIsVisible = false },
            new() { ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(RoleSelectionPage)),
                Route = nameof(RoleSelectionPage), FlyoutItemIsVisible = false }
        };

        Shell.Current.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var item in defaultItems) {
            Shell.Current.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
}

if I debug my shell, all the items are visible, so I do not undertand what is going on.
MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<AppShell, AppShellViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<RegisterStudentPage, RegisterStudentPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<NoInternetPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<NewLecturePage, NewLecturePageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<NewTestPage, NewTestPageViewMode>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ScheduleLecturePage, ScheduleLecturePageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ScheduleTestPage, ScheduleTestPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyCoursesPage, MyCoursesPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<JoinMeetingPage, JoinMeetingPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ManageCoursePage, ManageCoursePageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StartupPage, StartupPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<RoleSelectionPage, RoleSelectionPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<RoomPage, RoomPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyCoursesDetailPage, MyCoursesDetailPageViewModel>();

and because everything is generated dynamically, my shell.xaml is empty.
and in the shell code behind I construct the default pages
public partial class AppShell : Shell {
public AppShell(AppShellViewModel appShellViewModel) {

    InitializeComponent();
    // SetupNavigationView();
    BindingContext = appShellViewModel;

    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyCoursesDetailPage), typeof(MyCoursesDetailPage));
}

protected override void OnAppearing() {

    FlyoutHelper.GetDefaultMenuItems();

}

a


May I know what .NET version you are using? 2. Can you please help add some code in your post to reproduce the issue?


what part of the code, do you need? I am using .NET8


Is this issue happening only if FlyoutBehavior is defined as Locked? 2. Try to set the pages or vm as builder.Services.AddSingleton(). 3. You can also report it to Maui Github repo:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues


Is happening only when looked
I already tried singleton

Consider reporting the issue to Maui Github repo: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

The issue could be caused by not giving flyout enough time to update. See this relevant issue:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21865. To fix it, you may need to enable tabs on the shell so you can see it.
